# Display an image in avatar React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to display uploaded image inside the avatar so i wrote this code:

```
export default function App() {
  const handleChange = function loadFile(event){
    document.getElementById("avatar").src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} id="upload" accept="image/*"  style={{display:"none"}}/>
      <label htmlFor="upload">
        <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span">
        <Avatar  id="avatar"  src="/*photo URL using GetEvent */" 
              style={{

                        width: "60px",
                        height: "60px",
                     }}
    />
    </IconButton>
    </label>
    <label fro="avatar"></label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But unfortunately, the code run with and doesn't display the image! 
I tried to figure out where is my mistake but i didn't found it.

Comment: What is `Avatar`? Is it your model or thirdparty?

Comment: any errors in browser console? also, what happens when use `<img id="avatar"/>` instead?

Comment: Avatar is from Material ui library

Comment: No errors in browser console, and i tried with ```<img id=''avatar''/>``` and still can't display the uploaded image

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening. I can then try to look into this further.

Comment: Yes of course!
This is the URL of the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-currying-dnw9k?file=/App.js

Comment: There one error in the demo like `The tag <avatar> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.` Please fix this once and add the updated link here.

Comment: Here we go: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-flower-02u4w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think by mistake you posted a new sandbox which does not contain your code at all.

Comment: Oh sorry, here is it: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-flower-02u4w?file=/stackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hi, I have fixed your code. please check it.**

```
export default function App() {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = function loadFile(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            const file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            setFile(file);
        }
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} id="upload" accept="image/*" style={{display: "none"}}/>
            <label htmlFor="upload">
                <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span">
                    <Avatar id="avatar" src={file}
                            style={{

                                width: "60px",
                                height: "60px",
                            }}
                    />
                </IconButton>
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="avatar"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```